# Inheriting from Partial Classes

Tags: wcf, inheritance, partial-classes

I have a pretty serious problem.  I have an application that has a partial class that is spread out across several folders in my Project.  I am trying to create a daughter object that has all the functionality of this object (this is a WCF webservice and I want to make sure that I have all the functionality of that first service before I add on or expand on it).  However, for some reason, after I inherit from that object I can't seem to access all the functionality of the first class?  I am not sure what I am doing wrong?  I can't show any real code segments because it is proprietary, but here is an example.

public partial class OriginalService : IwantThisThing2Work{ //In here the functionality of the Interface is implemented, I just don't feel like writing dummy functionality }

public partial class OriginalService : IwantThisThing2Fail{//In here the functionality of the Interface is implemented, I just don't feel like writing dummy functionality }

public partial class OriginalService : IsomeInterface{//In here the functionality of the Interface is implemented, I just don't feel like writing dummy functionality }

public class Secondservice : OriginalService {//All of the functionality should be in here}

Now, for some reason, I only seem to get the functionality of the first two and not the rest of the functionality.  I am not really sure what else I can do?  There is not a lot of documentation on the topic that I can think of.  The only thing I can think of is maybe there are some dependecies that I am missing or something during compelation.

Any Ideas fellow coders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK.  I think I figured it out.  I forgot to add all of the contract endpoints to my web.config file.  I did in fact add the contract's for the two endpoints that I could access.

To be more clear, the person who wrote the original service divided his contract up among several smaller contracts (I guess to separate concern... or SOC).  He implemented the contracts by creating one class but dividing it up using partial classes.  When I attempted to change the security protocols of the WCF service by implementing WShttpBinding, I only tested the first two contracts he created and I only added those two endpoints.  After struggling to get the WSHttpBinding working (setting up a certificate on the server and on my machine... Never did that before) I completely forgot to add the rest of the endpoints.  So even though I implemented them in driver of the contracts, they would never be exposed, thus my weeping and nashing of teeth, and fear of Job losses for not being able to perform the simplest of tasks.

Just one more question, what do you guys think of the separation of contracts and implementing them through partial classes?  Is that part of some design pattern that I am not aware of?

Thanks,
Idiot Developer.

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided much information to go on here but I would check that namespaces of all the partial classes are consistent.